# How to Select single cell in CollectionView and deselecting all other cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**

> I have horizontal CollectionView in which selected cell have orange
>   gradient color and all other deselected cells gray color i m
>   using only didselect delegate method but i am getting problem of
>   multiple cells selected and i have problem with same concept in table
>   view while scrolling and i have searched a lot but i have not get
>   proper answer of cell reusability

**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    DateTimeCell * cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DateTimeCellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    if (self.selectedIndexPath != nil && indexPath == self.selectedIndexPath)
    {

        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = cell.mainView.bounds;
        gradient.startPoint = CGPointZero;

        gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:238.0/255.0 green:42.0/255.0 blue:123/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:90.0/255.0 blue:41.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];
        [gradient setMasksToBounds:NO];
        cell.mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.mainView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

        [indexPaths addObject:self.selectedIndexPath];

    }
     else
     {
         [cell.mainView setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"383F4A"]];
      }

    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];

    if (self.selectedIndexPath)
    {
        // if we had a previously selected cell

        if ([indexPath compare:self.selectedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            // if it's the same as the one we just tapped on, then we're unselecting it

            NSLog(@"Selected");

        }
        else
        {
            // if it's different, then add that old one to our list of cells to reload, and
            // save the currently selected indexPath

            [indexPaths addObject:self.selectedIndexPath];
            self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // else, we didn't have previously selected cell, so we only need to save this indexPath for future reference

        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    }



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    });


}
```

Comment: You need to reload all rows for this.

Comment: multiple cells are getting selected on single click now..

Comment: Manage your required selected Cell's in after reload.

Comment: can u give some sample plz

Comment: It looks straight forward! Keep track of Indexes of cell's that you required in selected mode, Else are deselected. Use this logic after reload.

Comment: with this approach i m getting one problem when i deselect cell deselect method is getting called after this did selec is also getting called why ..?? and i have used
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
    self.collectionView.allowsSelection = YES; //this is set by default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137200/discussion-between-sharma-vishal-and-salman-siddiqui).

Answer (score 2):

take a global selectedIndexPath globaly like below

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

wrilte below code in delegate methods

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


DateTimeCell * cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DateTimeCellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if self.selectedIndexPath == indexPath
{
  // do what you want to do with your selected cell
}
else
{
    // do what you want to do with your deselected cell
}


return cell;
}

 -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
[self.collectionView reloadData];


 }
```

Comment: in .h file where you have outlet of your collectionview